# Enlightn run very slowly take 2 minute to run

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-artisan

Enlightn runs very slowly - takes 2 minutes to boot. Looking for suggestions.

Configuration: "enlightn/enlightnpro": "1.*", laravel 8 , php 8.1

**Issue description:**

- When I hit `php artisan enlightn` command, it consumes more time to run.
- When I run on production, my site is down.

**We have tried to resolve this using below steps, all without effect:**

1. We have installed *queue setup* and this slows down, so we have uninstalled and removed *queue configuration*.
2. We have also tried `php -d memory_limit=512M artisan enlightn`.
3. We have installed and uninstalled Enlightn.

**Other observations:**

- Checked local system space: no issue regarding space.
- This check in Enlightn takes more time: Constructor injection is not used in non-lazy loaded commands. Passed.

Comment: Are there any log files you can check? At least the webserver should provide some which catches the PHP errors, if there are any.

Comment: Yes, we have checked the log file, and we have not found any errors.

Comment: Maybe there is no error, it just does tasks which are synchronous. Without any code to debug it is hard to tell. You could log any steps in the command for yourself to see where it bottlenecks.